# Titanium: WebView using Navigation Bar

Tags: webview, navigation, titanium, back, nav

I'm using Titanium.
I am trying to show web page with navigation bar.

I want to put Back button at the top left position inside navigation bar which works as browser's back.

Below is my current code.

Could anybody help me with this??

Thanks in advance.

```
 var w = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    leftNavButtonLabel:'back',});
var navGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
  window:w
});

var backBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
      title:'Back',
   style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
});

var webView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url : 'http://gooogle.com',
    canGoBack : true,
});

backBtn.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    webview.goBack();
});

w.add.setLeftNavButton(backBtn);

w.add(webView);

w.add(navGroup);

w.open();

w.navGroup.open();
```

Comment: this is fully wrong coding....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, This... or

```
var main_win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
});

var w = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    leftNavButtonLabel:'back',

});
var navGroup = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
  window:w
});

var backBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
      title:'Back',
   style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
});

var webView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url : 'http://gooogle.com',
    canGoBack : true,
});

backBtn.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    webview.goBack();// Goes back one entry in the web view's history list. to the previous page.

});

w.add.setLeftNavButton(backBtn);

w.add(webView);

main_win.add(navGroup);

main_win.open();

for Navigation new window


         navGroup.open(Window name);

for Closing last open window;

         navGroup.close(Window name);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I studied more and alos got to know how to manage through using tabgroup. Anyways, it helped me a lot!